How to make a bibliography with Biber
I have an issue with Miktex:
I have a .bib files from Zotero and i would like to use the reference in it.
I use compostion with pdfLatex on my document, and Biber in my .bib file, but it tell:\
INFO - This is Biber 2.19
INFO - Logfile is 'Ma bibliothèque.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find 'Ma bibliothèque.bcf'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1\
And i can't find the .bcf file anywhere
Someone have an idea for resolve the probleme ?
Thanks if you find somethings
AM

the bcf file will be made if your tex file uses \usepackage{biblatex}  if you are not using biblatex then use bibtex not biber to generate the bibliography. note for biber or bibtex you should use the name of the main tex file, not the name of your bib file as the argument to the command

Are you running Biber on the (basename of) your main file or on your .bib file? Like LaTeX, Biber is best run on the basename of your main .tex file. In your editor that means that you probably shouldn't have the .bib file in focus when you run Biber, but your main .tex file.
